# SipApi not supported by some device

Tags: android, sip, sipdroid

I am using native sip apis to implement sip calling in android app and it is working fine but in some devices like CANVAS 3  it was not working .After debugging  I found this line of code was returning **NULL**

```
 **manager = SipManager.newInstance(ctx);**
```

That measns that device does not support Sip Apis.But on the same device other application for sipcalling like SipDroid etc are working properly.How it is possible ?Are they do not use native sip Apis???

Comment: you can build your own lib for Sip

Comment: @SilentKiller ok so will that lib not use native sip apis ???

Comment: nopes. all classes will be in JNI.

Comment: @SilentKiller can you provide me some link where I can find how to do this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to complement SilentKiller response I would forward my answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20242864/1419134) question but, please, keep in mind that choosing a stack is a quite complex task and depends of your goals and preferences.

---

Android SIP Stack relays on an old [JAIN SIP](https://jsip.java.net/) version plus some extensions (IMS, supporting RTP, etc.). Main problem with this stack is that, in most devices, it only works via WiFi, no 3G or LTE (note that `android.net.sip.SipManager` contains method `isSipWifiOnly` to know if this limitation is enabled).

On the other hand, `pjsip` is quite complete, like they say, it's not a SIP stack but a full multimedia communications library. It's really versatile: you can use a huge number of configuration or just run it as a [simple user agent](http://svn.pjsip.org/repos/pjproject/trunk/pjsip-apps/src/samples/simple_pjsua.c). It works with any kind of data connection (not limited to WiFi).

Now the comparison: In my opinion, `pjsip` is more complete and versatile but more difficult to integrate with you project (with Android SIP Stack everything remains in the SDK environment while, with `pjsip`, you would need to use the NDK and a JNI library).

My opinion: If you plan to create a very simple SIP app and you don't mind the WiFi limitation, I think, the best would be using native SIP API but, if you plan to improve it and do something more "interesting", I would strongly recommend `pjsip`. I've used both JAIN SIP and `pjsip` and, again, my vote goes for `psip`. But this is just my opinion.

---

There's also another third party stack that worths checking: [Linphone](http://www.linphone.org/eng/documentation/dev/liblinphone-free-sip-voip-sdk.html). It is also integrated into your project with a JNI (like pjsip) and is also quite complete but, maybe, a bit more complex and heavy.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for such a brief  and easy explanation.I tried to integrate pjsip by following steps provided by it but as you already know its quite complex so can you please guide me how should I start it ,I mean what should I need to learn first .

Comment: also in device where it is not working I checked method IsSipWifiOnly and it returned false that means no problem regarding wifi .

Comment: @Bansal_Sneha Yes, no problem. First step is to get used to build pjsip for android, please, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20194563/1419134) response to get a step by step guide of this.

Comment: sorry for this question but  I am not getting how to implement pjsip lib in my  so I have build csipsipmple project and it is well running .Can you please tell me how to use its jni or is it possible to use it or not ?

Comment: @Bansal_Sneha Sorry but, although I've some experience with CSipSimple source code, I don't know its JNI very well. Of course it would be possible to use it in your project (you can check src/com/csipsimple/pjsip package to get some hint about how to interact with generated library) but, I think, it would be quite complex. Usually, you should create a JNI library wrapping pjsua calls and add it to your project. You can use pjsip-apps/src/samples/simple_pjsua.c (very simple SIP client) as reference to create this wrapper.

Answer (score 5):

you can go with custom SipLibraries.

**Third party open source sip stacks library for Android**

1. Jain sip: http://jsip.java.net/
2. Pjsip: http://www.pjsip.org/
3. Mjsip: http://mjsip.org/mjua.html
4. Doubango: http://www.doubango.org/

There are different open source projects which have used these libraries in their projects.

1. Jain sip: Not used in a "famous" app.
2. Sipdroid uses MjSip
3. Csipsimple uses PjSip
4. Imsdroid uses doubango.

Open source SIP stacks: Android SDK's default implementation (API > 9)
Advantages : Documentation available. Easy to understand.
Disadvantages : Not all devices are supported due carriers restriction. Works on WiFi only. Can't change codecs.

Third party: JainSIP
Advantages : Oracle (Sun) project ==> Active development. Looks easier than MjSIP (more documentation).
Disadvantages : None
[Android 2.3 using external JAIN-SIP(J-SIP) Stack | Classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5801107/android-2-3-using-external-jain-sipj-sip-stack-classpath)

Third party: MjSIP
Advantages : SipDroid is built on it. (source code available) (red5phone is another project) 
Disadvantages : Not fully compliant with RFC?. Lack of tutorials (Javadocs available though).Development almost dead

Third party: Doubango framework
Advantages : IMSDroid is built on it. (source code available)
Disadvantages : Generated apk file size tend to be "heavy" (>15MB as mentioned here)

Followed [from](http://www.basic4ppc.com/android/forum/threads/third-party-open-source-sip-stacks-library-for-android-over-b4a.27966/)

Comment: Man, your post is exactly like [this](http://www.basic4ppc.com/android/forum/threads/third-party-open-source-sip-stacks-library-for-android-over-b4a.27966/) ;-)

Comment: @jcm i think i had given the link also. may be updated by someone.

Comment: sorry, I didn't want to upset only that I recalled the post and thinking that mrodriguez was not very fair regarding Jain SIP.

Comment: @jcm its nothing like i had added that link as i had used that thing only. but dont know where that link gone so added again no upset every thing is up and set.. ;)

Comment: I think my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15605924/1449056) was copied twice.