# SipDemo or Sipdroid?

Tags: android, sip, voip

I want to develop my own app which can make VOIP calls, pls suggest should I start customizing the android sample project SipDemo or Sipdroid?
I am very new in this field, kindly help me. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

please note that choosing a SIP stack/application is a very personal subject, mainly based on your preferences and goals. I would suggest you to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20582407/1419134) question with a brief list of most popular SIP stacks for Android.

I've no experience with Sipdroid but, in my humble opinion and, based on my experience working with Android's own SIP stack, I found it very buggy and unstable. On the other hand, you also have other very complete open source possibilities like CSipSimple that would, most probably, cover all your current and future needs.

Hope this helps.